# java.net.UnknownHostException when using apache http client

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using HttpClient to connect to some third party url.Its working fine.but some times its giving java.net.UnknownHostException and also connection Reset Excetion. Please help to avoid the exception.

Below is my code snippet.

```
    PostMethod post = null;
 try
 {
     for(int i =0 ; i < 72 ; i++)
     {
        String url ="http://www.accuweather.com/en/in/amritsar/205593//hourly-weather-forecast/205593?hour=0";
        post = new PostMethod(url);
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "UTF-8");
        post.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 120000);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 120000);

        result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
     }
 }
 catch(Exception e){}
 finaly
 {
     post.releaseConnection();
 }
```

Belowe is the exception trace:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.accuweather.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$1.doit(ControllerThreadSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ControllerThreadSocketFactory$SocketTask.run(ControllerThreadSocketFactory.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error and trace.

Comment: When I open the url in the browser it shows 404 error. Please check the url.

Comment: Sorry, edited the URL now it will open in broweser. Please check.

Comment: Make sure you have an internet connection and permission internet in manifest.

Comment: @ anderson_acs : i need to run it for every hour.Sometimes its working.some times its giving that exception.

Comment: Are you accessing thru a proxy

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you just have a flaky Internet connection. I'm guessing this is on a mobile phone, in which case flaky Internet connections are a common reality, and you'll just have to deal with it in some way.

Exactly what is the best way to deal with it depends on your program and context, of course. Since you state you run this regularly, one way to deal with it could be to simply ignore an error (catch the exception and just silently abort the attempt if it happens) and then wait for the next regular run. Another option could be to repeat the attempt a set number of times. I'm sure there are other conceivable ways as well.